# Least square fit for data with uncertainty

Tags: least-squares, measurement-error, uncertainty

I have a set of data $\{x_i,y_i\}$ that came from my measurement, so each of them has some uncertainty. I wonder is there a method to fit them using a model (like Gaussian), while taking care of those uncertainties? In my previous experience on the least-squares fit, I only used the data and didn't take uncertainties in measurement into account. Thanks!

Comment: This is quite an extensive topic. The field of econometrics is largely concerned with the problem of endogeneity, or measurement error more specifically. Most solutions as far as I know solve this problem by using some sort of instrumental variable approach. How to deal with the problem of measurement error depends on your model, the source/kind of measurement error and your method of estimation. I highly recommend these lecture notes by [Pischke](https://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec524/Merr_new.pdf).

Comment: @confused student Thanks so much!

Comment: For this kind of problem, context is very important! Why do you have measurement errors, what is the measurement process? Are error variances in x and y comparable? ... Without such information nobody will be able to say more than generalities. Does some of the posts under [tag:total-least-squares] help? Or is the problem endogeneity? ...